# Modelica parameters as inputs

Tags: modelica

Consider the following simple package.

```
package Test

  connector Param
    parameter Real k = 1.5;
  end Param;

  model Component
    input Param p;
    Real x;
  equation 
    der(x) = p.k;
  end Component;

  model System
    Param p;
    Component c;
  equation 
    connect(p, c.p);
  end System;

end Test;
```

This works fine but as soon as I change `System.p.k` in the simulation, I get the following error:

```
abs(p.k-c.p.k) <= 0.0
The following error was detected at time: 0
Parameters in connected connectors must be equal
Error: Failed to start model.
```

Somehow the variables `p.k` and `c.p.k` are not aliasing each other. Hence, when I change only `p.k`, a discrepancy is detected which is not allowed since both have to be equal due to the equations induced by `connect(p, c.p)`.

How can I use parameters as inputs properly and avoid these effects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version of OpenModelica are you using?
For me this doesn't happen.
The simulation works fine:

```
adrpo@ida-liu050 ~/dev/OpenModelica/build/bin/
$ ./omc TestConnectionParameter.mos
true
""
record SimulationResult
    resultFile = "c:/bin/cygwin/home/adrpo/dev/OpenModelica/build/bin/media/TestConnectionParameter.System_res.mat",
    simulationOptions = "startTime = 0.0, stopTime = 1.0, numberOfIntervals = 500, tolerance = 1e-006, method = 'dassl', fileNamePrefix = 'TestConnectionParameter.System', options = '', outputFormat = 'mat', variableFilter = '.*', cflags = '', simflags = ''",
    messages = "",
    timeFrontend = 0.01857038093533281,
    timeBackend = 0.009237455657633623,
    timeSimCode = 0.002007941686540131,
    timeTemplates = 0.06294835594000042,
    timeCompile = 2.89228755603547,
    timeSimulation = 0.463245543628269,
    timeTotal = 3.4489112421252
end SimulationResult;
"Warning: The initial conditions are not fully specified. Use +d=initialization for more information.
"
true
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
```

I'm using file: TestConnectionParameter.mo:

```
package TestConnectionParameter

  connector Param
    parameter Real k = 1.5;
  end Param;

  model Component
    input Param p;
    Real x;
  equation 
    der(x) = p.k;
  end Component;

  model System
    Param p;
    Component c;
  equation 
    connect(p, c.p);
  end System;

end TestConnectionParameter;
```

and the script: TestConnectionParameter.mos

```
loadFile("TestConnectionParameter.mo"); getErrorString();
simulate(TestConnectionParameter.System); getErrorString();
plot({c.x, p.k, c.p.k});
val(p.k, 0);
val(p.k, 0.5);
val(p.k, 1);
val(c.p.k, 0);
val(c.p.k, 0.5);
val(c.p.k, 1);
```

Getting:
[image]

Comment: I am not using OpenModelica but a commercial tool. After simulating the system, I set p.k to some value different from c.p.k in the variable browser of the simulation tab. This yields the error mentioned above. Does it not occur in OpenModelica? Besides, what is the correct behavior according to the Modelica semantics?

Comment: Ok, you change the value after compilation. I don't know if a tool is required to have the possibility of value change without recompilation. Some tools supports it, some may not. 
As to the correct behavior according to Modelica semantics I really don't know this time as is a matter of interpretation. 
You could open a ticket on it on the Modelica Trac.

Comment: You have an even more fundamental issue.  When connectors are connected, parameters are not set equal.  No equation is generated.  Instead, an assertion is generated that requires that the parameters be equal.  This is precisely why you are getting an error.  When you change one and not the other, you violate the assertion.

Comment: Replacing connect(p, c.p) by p = c.p does not work either since it yields an overdetermined system. I wonder how I can feed parameters through a system. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Either you sent it as a modification everywhere or you could use "inner parameter Real k = 1.5;" at the top level and "outer parameter Real k;" down in the hierarchy. The compiler will see the outer k as a reference to the inner k.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It would be great though if connect could be extended do parameter modifications.